# Why does this css/html display extra padding?

Tags: html, css, padding

For the past few days, I've been struggling with some odd spacing on a website I'm building. Originally, I thought it was a display issue with Chrome, but I've been able to duplicate the problem in IE8, IE9, Firefox and Safari. I'm using old school HTML/CSS for backwards compatibility, so I can say it's not IE handling of HTML5 or some other bleeding edge update.

While some of the solutions on line have led me to try different things including floating the hedad, nothing's been successful & I always have padding on one of the long sides.

I have stripped this down to the BAREST of essentials to reproduce the problem, and have included a screen shot of the padding I can see on my end. I would certianly appreciate another set or seven of eyes showing me what I missed.

EDIT: line height turned out to the the culprit on this one, but vertically aligning the image to top per suggestion left the *text* at the top of the div. My sense would be that the header tag would preserve the default value, but that the and the img tag within the header would override that. Or can I only have one vertical align per  div?

Second, is there a way to collapse line-height with CSS?

HTML CODE

```
<html>  
        <head>
             <title>Test</title>
             <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
        </head>
        <body>
             <div id="header">
             <img src="bluespacer.gif" height=125 width=400>
             TEST
             </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS CODE

```
#header {
        font: serif;
        color: blue;
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

My output looks like below

[image: screen capture]

and here's the bluespacer.gif; 1px x 1px. Look close, it's like a dust speck!

( [image: bluespacer.gif] )  <---

Comment: can you share your bluespacer.gif link ?

Comment: `vertical-align` is for inline child elements (such as your image), not the parent element.  So, if you had 2 images inside your div, each one can have its own `vertical-align` value.  http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong spot. It's not padding but line-height, that generates that white space.

Try to vertically align the image:

```
#header img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Explanation: In the default style, the image is placed on the baseline of text. That is, the lower edge aligns roughly with the lower edge of, say, the letter 'x'. But because text has descenders (like 'g' or 'j'), the surrounding box is drawn higher, which leads to the extra space below the image.

Comment: and so it is...which then leads to another set of questions: I'll edit and re-submit.

Comment: @dwwilson66 I'd say it's better to open new questions than modifying the existing.

Comment: The `vertical-align` value the OP is looking for is `text-bottom`:  http://jsfiddle.net/RTTjc/1/

Comment: I added a fork to your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwwilson66/WuBH8/ and while the spacer isn't there, you can see the img border...and a few pixels beneath it. Id be interested to know why your bottom align behaves differently from mine....

Comment: @cimmanon on my end, text-bottom yields the same results as http://jsfiddle.net/dwwilson66/W4Hgb/

Answer (score 1):

It's a weird issue. You can do this.

```
#header img { line-height: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#header img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: But then, "TEST" wraps below the image. I read the question, that that's not intended.

Comment: @Andrew Pope: added a fork, http://jsfiddle.net/dwwilson66/W4Hgb/ and I've got a.) padding on the left now, and b.) my background color is only one row high. I've gotta be missing something else here...I can see multiple working solutions that don't work on my end for whatever reason.

Comment: @dwwilson66 I get some of the problems you are mentioning if I use IE in quirks mode. What browser are you using? Do you still get the problems in different browsers?

Comment: @Andrew Pope - I started with Chrome/PC, then moved to IE8/PC. I also tested in Firefox/Mac and Safari/Mac. Jiggling heights and alignments are working for now...so I'm back to chrome.